# Filter results using Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, http, angular5

I use Angular5 with HttpClient. I created a service to fetch data from an JSON API URL.

This works perfect.

But now, I want to restrict the results with one criteria (spots.lat must be > minlat and < maxlat).

I try using map and forEach (see below the code part between ?????) but it doesn't work. How can I correct this?

```
...
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export interface Spot {
    lat: number,
    lng: number,
    spotname: sring
}
tempspots: <Spot[]>

@Injectable()
export class SpotService {
   private spoturl = '<JSON SERVICE URL>';
   constructor(
      private http: HttpClient,
      ...
   ) {}
   onGetAllSpots(minlat : number, maxlat : number) : Observable<Spot[]> {
      return this.http
      .get<Spot[]>(this.spoturl)
// ?????
      .map(spots => {
          spots.forEach(spot => {
             if (spot.lat > minlat && spot.lat < maxlat) {
                this.tempspots.push(spot);
             }
          })
          return this.tempspots;
      })
// ?????
   }
}
```

Comment: The filter operation probably sounds like what you are looking for: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html

Comment: If you have access to the backend code providing the data to you, it will be much better to do the filtering on the backend. If the backend is sending you 1000 data points but you only need 3 of them, it is still sending you all 1000 data points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your code to this, it should work

```
.map(spots => {
          const tempspots: <Spot[]> = [];
          spots.forEach(spot => {
             if (spot.lat > minlat && spot.lat < maxlat) {
                tempspots.push(spot);
             }
          })
          return tempspots;
      })
```

Another way is using filter

```
.map(spots => {
              return spots.filter(spot => { 
                  return spot.lat > minlat && spot.lat < maxlat;
              })
          })
```

Comment: @Michel_If it solves your issue, kindly mark my post as answer, so other people with same problem find which post will help them out

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version

```
.map(spots => spots.filter(spot => spot.lat > minlat && spot.lat < maxlat))
```